# broadcast message from Openfire to Spark/XMPP client using PHP / MySQL

Tags: jsp, openfire, broadcast, php-5.5

I am using Openfire 3.10.0 RTC Server (MySQL DB is "**openrtc**" @ localhost) and spark messenger. I can send Administrative or Broadcast Message to all users from

```
Admin Login => Sessions => Tools => Send Message => Send Administrative Message
```

I have **"intranet"** website with db **"intr"** for local/office staff. There is latest news section on front/home page of intranet. Whenever the admin adds latest news to the intranet, it is stored in MySQL table.

Is it possible to broadcast the same message to xmpp/ spark messenger that is either hit by php or stored in MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

I guess its too late to reply as its almost 2 years, you probably get the solution but may be someone else still looking for the answer. Here is the code which work for me.

```
      #Sender User name = foo
      #Sender User Password = ****
      #Receiver User name = bar
      #Server name = soo.com
      #Server IP = xx.xxx.xxx.xx
```

`require 'XMPPHP/XMPP.php'; //you must include XMPP.php file you will get all bunch of files from https://github.com/cweiske/xmpphp`

`$conn = new XMPPHP_XMPP('xx.xxx.xxx.xx', 5222, 'foo', '****', 'xmpphp', 'soo.com', true, XMPPHP_Log::LEVEL_INFO);`

```
 try {
         $conn->connect(500); //Connection with Timeout in seconds 
         $conn->processUntil('session_start'); //process session start
         $conn->presence(NULL, "available", "bar@soo.com");
         $conn->message('bar@soo.com', 'Test message!'); //Message
         $conn->disconnect(); //disconnect
    } catch (XMPPHP_Exception $e) {
        die($e->getMessage());
    }
```

Hope this help someone!